# error: assignment of read-only variable

Tags: c++

I have a main.h file and include `static const unsigned int TIME = 13;`
and i have and main.cpp file include

```
    int64_t Gettime(int nnow, int64_t never)


{ 
   static const bool TIME = true;

    if(nnow == 6)
    {
        TIME = 9; 
    }

    else if(nnow == 8)
    {
        TIME = 3; 
    }

    else if(nnow == 1)
    {
        TIME = 40;
    }

    else if(nnow > 190)
    {
        TIME = 4000000;
    }

    return TIME + never;
}
```

on compile i get main.cpp:56:24: error: assignment of read-only variable ‘TIME’
         TIME = 3;
              ^

i want to change the TIME variable from main.h using a main.cpp function any help ?

Comment: You have several variables called "TIME".

Answer (score 1):

The `TIME` variable is declared a `const`, so you will only be able to read its value but not modify it, that is what the compiler is letting you know in the error.

If you HAVE to modify that variable then you have to remove the `const` qualifier.

Comment: how i can make it writable ?

Comment: Change its declaration, remove the `const`.

Comment: remove the `const` qualifier or use a copy of it

Comment: i change it to static const unsigned int TIME = 13; but i get the same error

Comment: you also have mistakes,  you have another TIME variable declared in the scope `static const bool TIME = true;`, you need to either change the type (do you want it to be a bool?) and remove the `const` modifier from that one OR you have to fully qualify the path to the other `TIME` variable (the one in the other file)

Answer (score 0):

@shafeen answer is correct, but since it seems you aren't quite understanding it, how about some code?

Change this:

```
static const bool TIME = true;
```

To:

```
static bool TIME = true;
```

I would have put this as a comment to @shafeen's answer, but I don't have rep :(

Comment: it compiled without errors but when i run ./time -time return me 13 the TIME variable is not change any help ?

Comment: Well, you've declared TIME as a bool. Bool should only be used to store true/false or 0/1. You can change it from bool to int if you want to store integer values.

Comment: I'm newbie sorry if I become bored you mean like static int TIME = true; ?

Comment: Yes, that should work. But you shouldn't assign "true" to an 'int', you should assign an integer, such as 1 (to represent true) or 0 (to represent false).