# Correct answer for technical interview C problem

Tags: c

I have this code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

const float dAverage = 0;
const int a = 100;
const int b = 101;

int main(void) {
    int iProduct = 0;
    iProduct = a * b;
    dAverage = (a + b) / 2.0;

    printf("Product a*b =%d\n", iProduct);
    printf("Average of a,b=%.3f\n", dAverage);
    return 0;
}
```

The question is "What is the console output?"

So, when compiling, I get "main.c:9:13: error: assignment of read-only variable ‘dAverage’"

Why?

Comment: You've reassigned `dAverage`, which is a `const`, which causes an error. Once you declare a `const`, it is **constant** (no changes allowed). Change it to just `float dAverage = 0;`

Comment: Did you try to find an answer by searching for the exact error message?

Comment: Is there supposed to be output or are they trying to see if you understand `const`? This is a pretty goofy technical question.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [error: assignment of read-only variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35385779/error-assignment-of-read-only-variable)

Answer (score 2):

The current answer is an error as you are trying to alter a constant. If you meant the following instead:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
float dAverage = 0;
const int a=100;
const int b=101;

int main (void){
    int iProduct=0;
    iProduct=a*b;
    dAverage=(a+b)/2.0;

    printf("Product a*b =%d\n",iProduct);
    printf("Average of a,b=%.3f\n",dAverage);
    return 0;
}
```

then the output would be:

```
Product a*b =10100
Average of a,b=100.500
```